# How to add a parameter to JVM in Linux

Tags: jvm

I'm using kafka in linux and I want to pass the JAAS config file location as JVM parameter to the Kafka broker

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf
```

How to apply the command above ?

Thanks

Comment: maybe by just exporting an environment variable ?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? It may matter.

Comment: @David Ubuntu 20.04